# Why do we use snapshot in RTC

Tags: rtc

I've been reading about snapshot and doing it practically.
I got the idea of snapshot but I could not figure out why do we use snapshot.
could anyone please tell me what is use of snapshot in RTC, or any scenario where snapshot is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A snapshot is use to keep a coherent state of a stream ([multiple components and their current baselines/delivered change sets](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/58744/difference-between-snapshot-and-baseline)) or repo workspace.

For instance, when an RTC build is requested, RTC will start by making a snapshot on the build-dedicated repo workspace specified by the build definition, in order for the user to easily create a stream based on that snapshot later on, if the build is problematic and warrant its own debug environment.

A snapshot is very useful to initialize a stream in one operation: select a snapshot and *all* the component baselines included in that snapshot appear in the stream.

(Note that there is also a [snapshot in planning](https://jazz.net/library/article/658): here I was referring only to a source control snapshot)

Comment: Thank You VonC. I think snapshot can not be modified once created because it is collection of baseline from multiple components.

Comment: @vikrantkamble yes, that is the idea: it is an immutable picture of the state (at a given time) of your streeam or repo workspace: like a picture taken by a camera, that you cannot indeed modify once taken.